# How to adjust a custom .bst referencing style in natbib

Tags: citing, natbib, multiple-citations

I am using the `natbib` package with a custom referencing style for the Leeds Harvard style, downloaded from [here](https://github.com/lilythepooh/Leeds-Harvard-Style-Ref-for-LaTeX).

However, this style does not do exactly what I need.
An example of a reference using this style, looks like this:
[image]

While, what I need it to be is:
[image]

Essentially, I need three things:

1. Get rid of the parentheses around the year of publication,
2. Add dots after the title and the name of the journal,
3. Add "pp." right before the page numbers.

How can I achieve this? Is there a different referencing style that looks like this? Or will I have to copy all my references into Word and adjust it manually, which would mean losing the links between citations and reference?

The code I am using is:

```
@article{kearns2001significance,
  title={The significance of neighbourhood},
  author={Kearns, Ade and Parkinson, Michael},
  journal={Urban studies},
  volume={38},
  number={12},
  pages={2103--2110},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Sage Publications Sage UK: London, England}
}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{lsharvard.bst}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Some text that I'm citing \citep{kearns2001significance}.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Do you know how the `lsharvard` bibliography style was created? With the help of the `makebst` utililty?

Comment: Possibly, yes. How can I install this tool?

Comment: The `makebst` is part of the `custom-bib` package, which should be a part of every decent TeX distribution. Type `latex makebst` at a command prompt to get started. You'll be asked a long series of questions, each multiple-choice with a default indicated clearly. At the end, you'll get a bespoke bst file.

Comment: I am using overleaf, so I don't have latex installed locally. How can I install it then?